# Monitor Java Demon Process using Monit

Tags: java, server, monitor, pid, monit

Is there another way to monitor a running Java process than to use PID with Monit?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use monit without PID file. If your process does not create a PID file you will have to create a wrapper to start the program and create PID file for monit. See here in official Monit [FAQs](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#pidfile).

**Edit:**

Monit has a way other than PID file which is process name. But for this process name should be unique. From the [documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#THE-MONIT-CONTROL-FILE):

> 1. CHECK PROCESS [unique name] PIDFILE [path] | MATCHING [regex]
>
>    [path] is the absolute path to the program's pid-file. A pid-file is a file, containing a Process's unique ID. If the pid-file does not
>      exist or does not contain the PID number of a running process, Monit
>      will call the entry's start method if defined.
>
>    [regex] is an alternative to using PID files and uses process name pattern matching to find the process to monitor. The first match is
>      used so this form of check is most useful if the process name is
>      unique. Pid-file should be used where possible as it defines expected
>      pid exactly (pattern matching won't be useful for processes which
>      start a child process using fork/clone as the child will match the
>      same pattern temporarily). You can test if a process match a pattern
>      from the command-line using monit procmatch "regex-pattern". This will
>      lists all processes matching or not, the regex-pattern.